# Use ajax to process form

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a form where visitors can subscribe to a mailing list.

The code is:

```
    function subscribe_form() {
        global $my_subme;

        $form = '';
        $msg = '';

        if ( isset( $_GET['status'] ) ) {
            if ( 'subscribed' === $_GET['status'] ) {
                $msg = __( 'Thank you for confirming your subscription', 'subme' );
            } else if ( 'unsubscribed' === $_GET['status'] ) {
                $msg = __( 'You have successfully unsubscribed.', 'subme' );
            } else {
                $msg = __( 'Sorry, but something went wrong.', 'subme' );
            }

            $form .= '<p>';
            $form .= esc_html( $msg );
            $form .= '</p>';
        } else {
            /* Process the form when submitted */
            if ( ( isset( $_POST['subscribe'] ) || isset( $_POST['unsubscribe'] ) ) && isset( $_POST['source'] ) && 'widget' === $_POST['source'] ) {
                /* Check nonce */
                if ( ! isset( $_POST['subme_widget_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['subme_widget_nonce'], 'subme_widget' ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                if ( ! isset( $_POST['email'] ) ) {
                    return;
                }

                if ( ! $my_subme->is_valid_email( strtolower( $_POST['email'] ) ) ) {
                    $msg = __( 'Sorry, but this does not seem like a valid email address.', 'subme' );

                } else {
                    if ( isset( $_POST['subscribe'] ) ) {
                        $msg = $my_subme->subscribe( $_POST['email'] );
                    } else {
                        $msg = $my_subme->unsubscribe( $_POST['email'] );
                    }
                }
            }

            $form .= '<form method="post">';
            $form .= wp_nonce_field( 'subme_widget', 'subme_widget_nonce', true, false );
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="source" value="widget" />';
            $form .= '<p>';
            $form .= __( 'Your email address:', 'subme' ) . '<br />';
            $form .= '<input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />';
            $form .= '<input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="' . __( 'Subscribe', 'subme' ) . '" />';
            $form .= ' ';
            $form .= '<input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="' . __( 'Unsubscribe', 'subme' ) . '" />';
            $form .= '</p>';
            $form .= '</form>';

            if ( strlen( $msg ) > 0 ) {
                $form .= '<p>';
                $form .= esc_html( $msg );
                $form .= '</p>';
            }
        }

        echo $form;
        echo '</div>';

    }


subscribe_form();
```

How do I change this code so that it is processed using ajax? As you can see, currently it is a simply page refresh when user submits the form.

Comment: Why is that a function?

Comment: I have the form added in a plugin (which is not relevant to my question) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two submits, only the second one will be sent to the form... You need to do something like 2 forms, or add a onclick event to change the name or type or a hidden value... something like:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='subscribe'" value="Subscribe" />
<input type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='unsubscribe'" value="Unsubscribe" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1.- Its code that you show is php, ok. this is server side.

2.- From client side. You should have code javascript that send to server, the data saying this client want to subscribe.

Comment: How would the javascript code look when considering my code? Can you please provide code example?